# Solving differing Windows 8.1's DPI issues

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, resolution, dpi

I am trying to extend my 13.9 3200x1800 (~264.14PPI) laptop with a 27" 2560x1440 (~108.79PPI) Dell Ultrasharp as top-down set up.

But I am having issues with Windows 8.1's DPI scaling. Tweaking the scaling level settings, either:

- the Dell U2715H is blurred/fuzzy and the laptop is fine
- the Dell U2715H is fine or the laptop's display scaling is too large
- setting the scale level for all displays, or disabling display scaling for specific apps makes them appear too large on the Dell

Is there a way I can improve on how Windows handles the DPI for my displays? Right now I am just using the Dell as the primary display when stationary with the laptop display disabled, but I would rather utilise both displays. Without.